# SerializationProxy pattern gives ClassCastException: How to avoid?

Tags: java, serialization, classcastexception, circular-reference

I have the following two classes that use the *Serialization Proxy* pattern from the *Effective Java* book. I suppose I am running into trouble due to circular dependencies, how would I be able to solve it?

```
public class Symbol implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 23829245030202L;

    private final String symbol;
    private final float confidence;
    private final boolean dropcap;
    private final boolean subscript;
    private final boolean superscript;
    private final Rectangle boundingBox;
    private final Rectangle baseline;
    private final List<SymbolChoice> symbolChoices;

    private Word parentWord;

    private Symbol(final String symbol, final float confidence, final boolean dropcap, final boolean subscript, final boolean superscript, final Rectangle boundingBox, final Rectangle baseline, final List<SymbolChoice> symbolChoices) {
        this.symbol = Objects.requireNonNull(symbol, "symbol");
        this.confidence = confidence;
        this.dropcap = dropcap;
        this.subscript = subscript;
        this.superscript = superscript;
        this.boundingBox = Objects.requireNonNull(boundingBox, "boundingBox");
        this.baseline = Objects.requireNonNull(baseline, "baseline");
        this.symbolChoices = Objects.requireNonNull(symbolChoices, "symbolChoices");
    }

    private void setParentWord(final Word parentWord) {
        this.parentWord = Objects.requireNonNull(parentWord, "parentWord");
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public float getConfidence() {
        return confidence;
    }

    public boolean isDropcap() {
        return dropcap;
    }

    public boolean isSubscript() {
        return subscript;
    }

    public boolean isSuperscript() {
        return superscript;
    }

    public Rectangle getBoundingBox() {
        return boundingBox;
    }

    public Rectangle getBaseline() {
        return baseline;
    }

    public List<SymbolChoice> getSymbolChoices() {
        return symbolChoices;
    }

    public Word getParentWord() {
        return parentWord;
    }

    public static class SymbolBuilder {
        private final String symbol;
        private final float confidence;
        private final boolean dropcap;
        private final boolean subscript;
        private final boolean superscript;
        private final Rectangle boundingBox;
        private final Rectangle baseline;
        private final List<SymbolChoice> symbolChoices = new ArrayList<SymbolChoice>();

        public SymbolBuilder(final String symbol, final float confidence, final boolean dropcap, final boolean subscript, final boolean superscript, final Rectangle boundingBox, final Rectangle baseline) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.confidence = confidence;
            this.dropcap = dropcap;
            this.subscript = subscript;
            this.superscript = superscript;
            this.boundingBox = boundingBox;
            this.baseline = baseline;
        }

        public SymbolBuilder addSymbolChoice(final SymbolChoice symbolChoice) {
            symbolChoices.add(Objects.requireNonNull(symbolChoice, "symbolChoice"));
            return this;
        }

        public Symbol build() {
            return new Symbol(symbol, confidence, dropcap, subscript, superscript, boundingBox, baseline, symbolChoices);
        }
    }

    private Object writeReplace() {
        return new SerializationProxy(this);
    }

    private void readObject(final ObjectInputStream stream) throws InvalidObjectException {
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Proxy required");
    }

    private static class SerializationProxy implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 49545459839839843L;

        private final String symbol;
        private final float confidence;
        private final boolean dropcap;
        private final boolean subscript;
        private final boolean superscript;
        private final Rectangle boundingBox;
        private final Rectangle baseline;
        private final List<SymbolChoice> symbolChoices;

        private final Word parentWord;

        private SerializationProxy(final Symbol symbol) {
            this.symbol = symbol.symbol;
            this.confidence = symbol.confidence;
            this.dropcap = symbol.dropcap;
            this.subscript = symbol.subscript;
            this.superscript = symbol.superscript;
            this.symbolChoices = symbol.symbolChoices;
            this.boundingBox = symbol.boundingBox;
            this.baseline = symbol.baseline;
            this.parentWord = symbol.parentWord;
        }

        private Object readResolve() {
            Symbol localSymbol = new Symbol(symbol, confidence, dropcap, subscript, superscript, boundingBox, baseline, symbolChoices);
            localSymbol.setParentWord(parentWord);
            return localSymbol;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Word implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9084633893292833L;

    private final String word;
    private final float confidence;
    private final FontAttributes fontAttributes;
    private final boolean fromDictionary;
    private final boolean numeric;
    private final Rectangle boundingBox;
    private final Rectangle baseline;
    private final List<Symbol> symbols;

    private Textline parentTextline;

    private Word(final String word, final float confidence, final FontAttributes fontAttributes, final boolean fromDictionary, final boolean numeric, final Rectangle boundingBox, final Rectangle baseline, final List<Symbol> symbols) {
        this.word = Objects.requireNonNull(word, "word");
        this.confidence = confidence;
        this.fontAttributes = Objects.requireNonNull(fontAttributes, "fontAttributes");
        this.fromDictionary = fromDictionary;
        this.numeric = numeric;
        this.boundingBox = Objects.requireNonNull(boundingBox, "boundingBox");
        this.baseline = Objects.requireNonNull(baseline, "baseline");
        this.symbols = Objects.requireNonNull(symbols, "symbols");
    }

    private void setParentTextline(final Textline parentTextline) {
        this.parentTextline = Objects.requireNonNull(parentTextline, "parentTextline");
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public float getConfidence() {
        return confidence;
    }

    public FontAttributes getFontAttributes() {
        return fontAttributes;
    }

    public boolean isFromDictionary() {
        return fromDictionary;
    }

    public boolean isNumeric() {
        return numeric;
    }

    public Rectangle getBoundingBox() {
        return boundingBox;
    }

    public Rectangle getBaseline() {
        return baseline;
    }

    public List<Symbol> getSymbols() {
        return symbols;
    }

    public Textline getParentTextline() {
        return parentTextline;
    }

    public static class WordBuilder {
        private final String word;
        private final float confidence;
        private final FontAttributes fontAttributes;
        private final boolean fromDictionary;
        private final boolean numeric;
        private final Rectangle boundingBox;
        private final Rectangle baseline;
        private final List<Symbol> symbols = new ArrayList<Symbol>();

        public WordBuilder(final String word, final float confidence, final FontAttributes fontAttributes, final boolean fromDictionary, final boolean numeric, final Rectangle boundingBox, final Rectangle baseline) {
            this.word = word;
            this.confidence = confidence;
            this.fontAttributes = fontAttributes;
            this.fromDictionary = fromDictionary;
            this.numeric = numeric;
            this.boundingBox = boundingBox;
            this.baseline = baseline;
        }

        public WordBuilder addSymbol(final Symbol symbol) {
            symbols.add(Objects.requireNonNull(symbol, "symbol"));
            return this;
        }

        public Word build() {
            return new Word(word, confidence, fontAttributes, fromDictionary, numeric, boundingBox, baseline, symbols);
        }
    }

    private Object writeReplace() {
        return new SerializationProxy(this);
    }

    private void readObject(final ObjectInputStream stream) throws InvalidObjectException {
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Proxy required");
    }

    private static class SerializationProxy implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 794943938877393932L;

        private final String word;
        private final float confidence;
        private final FontAttributes fontAttributes;
        private final boolean fromDictionary;
        private final boolean numeric;
        private final Rectangle boundingBox;
        private final Rectangle baseline;
        private final List<Symbol> symbols;

        private final Textline parentTextline;

        private SerializationProxy(final Word word) {
            this.word = word.word;
            this.confidence = word.confidence;
            this.fontAttributes = word.fontAttributes;
            this.fromDictionary = word.fromDictionary;
            this.numeric = word.numeric;
            this.boundingBox = word.boundingBox;
            this.baseline = word.baseline;
            this.symbols = word.symbols;
            this.parentTextline = word.parentTextline;
        }

        private Object readResolve() {
            Word localWord = new Word(word, confidence, fontAttributes, fromDictionary, numeric, boundingBox, baseline, symbols);
            localWord.setParentTextline(parentTextline);
            return localWord;
        }
    }
}
```

Gives exception:

```
cannot assign instance of com.skiwi.tessutils4j.data.Word$SerializationProxy 
to field com.skiwi.tessutils4j.data.Symbol$SerializationProxy.parentWord 
of type com.skiwi.tessutils4j.data.Word in instance 
of com.skiwi.tessutils4j.data.Symbol$SerializationProxy
```

Note that these two classes are not the only ones to have such dependency.

To comment on my design here: I have a hierarchy of:

```
Block -> Paragraph -> Textline -> Word -> Symbol -> SymbolChoice
```

All elements need to have a list of children, and all elements (except `SymbolChoice`) need to know their parent.

How can I avoid this exception, possibly with a design change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is to realize that the parent information is not worth serializing in the child.

In your hierarchy:

```
Block -> Paragraph -> Textline -> Word -> Symbol -> SymbolChoice
```

if you are serializing any one of those classes, that class should serialize itself, and it's children, but not it's parent. The parent can be set after deserializing.

In other words, for example, you should not have `parentWord` and `this.parentWord = symbol.parentWord;` in the Symbol's `SerializationProxy`. Instead, in the Word's `SerializationProxy`, the code should look like:

```
    private Object readResolve() {
        Word localWord = new Word(word, confidence, fontAttributes, fromDictionary, numeric, boundingBox, baseline, symbols);
        for (Symbol s : symbols) {
            s.setParentWord(localWord);
        }
        return localWord;
    }
```

This changes the order of references to match the deserialization order, and removes the cycles.

Comment: Thats all well and good if you have an acyclic directed graph. But you are SOL if an object reference transitively references the enclosing entity. This is easily possible if the relationship is not parent-child. Imagine serializing one side of a many-to-many relationship where the relation is represented by a join entity. This is a very common case in JPA - where all entities are required by the spec to implement Serializable. If you also try to use SerializationProxy in this scenario you will encounter this serious deficiency in Java Serialization.